# Use STM32 as a mouse and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, stm32

I finished using Stm32 as a mouse and keyboard one by one but I don't know how to combine both at the same time. I followed this guide https://damogranlabs.com/2016/03/stm32-custom-usb-hid-device-yes-please/ but what should I change in **usbd_hid_core.c**?

Any help would be greatly appreciated and if anyone has questions about setting up a mouse or keyboard, I would be happy to answer.

Comment: The way the question stands right now it's pretty much a request for someone to do your work. What have you tried, what has worked, what hasn't?

Comment: the author of tutorial seem very active in the comments. Its always better to post your doubts there, as it will involve much lesser talking and get directly to your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two ways:

1. Make a so called USB composite device with two functions - one mouse, another keyboard. Google for examples om GitHub an other places.
2. Pure HID implementation. Each function will be a so called HID collection.  You'll need to create a HID report descriptor with two (or more) top level collections.
   With this approach, USB composite stuff is not needed, the device can have only one function. This is much simpler than composite design, with less resources. But some old computers or host devices don't understand HID collections.